# Adding to Array-List doesn't work in For-Loop

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add data to an ArrayList inside a For-Loop and it doesn't work.

I've got a Cloud Firestore in Firebase with a collection filled with documents by another app. This one is meant to get the data and put it in a Recycler View. Adapter and all are set. Far as I can see, the problem is with filling the (Array)list inside the For-Loop? (As also just filling in any data inside this loop doesn't work, but I'm not sure.)
I noted some of my tries and errors in the code using comments. I'm sure, it must be just some minor mistake, but I really can't find it.
Adding data with the exact same code outside the For-Loop works, inside doesn't work (see "Blah")

```
private ArrayList<String> patients;

private String testString;
//-> String einzig zu Testzwecken

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    patients = new ArrayList<>();

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    db.collection("Test")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                            //patients = new ArrayList<>();
                            //-> doesn't work

                            patients.add((document.getData().toString()));
                            //doesn't work

                            listData.add(new Data(R.drawable.hohlbrot, "ahjotest"));
                            //doesn't work (trying to feed the recyclerView more directly)

                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, document.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //textView.setText(document.getData().toString());

                                // -> both work
                            testString = testString + document.getData().toString();
                            textView.setText(testString);
                                // -> works
                            patients.add("Blah1");
                            //doesn't work

                            //Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        patients.add("BlahError");
                    }
                }
            });


    patients.add("Blah2");
      //works
```

Well, I tried several things, but with the setting, that I would expect to work, there were no error messages. It just didn't do anything. In the RecyclerView the "Blah2" occurs as do any Strings I add later. Anything I tried inside the For-Loop (Toast, String-to-TextView,...) actually worked, as long as it didn't use the ArrayList.

PS: Me am Noob, beg your patience -.-

Comment: have a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android

Comment: the reason you're having this problem is because you're coding as if everything runs from "top-down" or synchronously, but it actually doesn't because it's firebase, which returns asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

try to run your for loop inside OnSuccessListener if you are using firebase.

the syntax is similar to this:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("some collection").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                     //do your work here
            })
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thank you so far. I now tried (among others), but still doesn't work. 

db.collection("Test")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            patients.add((documentSnapshot.getData().toString()));
                        }
                    }
                });

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it running with the solutions/approaches mentioned, but I rebuild it following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=ub6mNHWGVHw&feature=emb_title

-> so using the Firestore RecyclerView (instead of the normal one) and the given setup (no For-Loop involved).